# ActionScript 3 package structure and directory structure

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I seem to run into compile issues in Flash Builder when I import 3rd-party libraries at the wrong level in the directory structure.

For example, sometimes I'll import a library one level too deep into its directory tree, and the package explorer ends up excluding the prefix root-level package, usually "com." or "net.". Even though the content of the source itself doesn't change, this will cause compile errors.

Thus:

- Is it a 1) convention or 2) language requirement that a class's package structure (e.g., "foo.bar.Class") must match its path location (e.g., foo/bar/Class.as)?
- If it's a language requirement, *why* is it a requirement? Wouldn't that overdetermine the package structure, since it is already specified in the source code and quite happily consuming the first three to eight columns of each line?
- If it's not a language requirement, are my compile errors just a result of Flash Builder enforcing the convention?

Comment: Sounds like you should go back and learn some fundamentals around AS3 and OOP. Have a good read of this - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/oop_as3.html

Comment: No doubt I'm pretty new to AS3, but I'm not sure if it's a requirement of OOP at large to double-specify packages (or their language-specific equivalents) in both source code and file structure. I see value in such a habit as a practical convention, but I guess I have to admit to feeling a bit of aesthetic discomfort at the idea that this is a compiler requirement. There are languages that can organize themselves without so much redundancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a language requirement, and it's one that ActionScript shares with Java.  The [Wikipedia article on Java packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions) offers a fitting description:

> The Java Language
>   Specification establishes package
>   naming conventions to avoid the
>   possibility of two published packages
>   having the same name. The naming
>   conventions describe how to create
>   unique package names, so that packages
>   that are widely distributed will have
>   unique namespaces. This allows
>   packages to be separately, easily and
>   automatically installed and
>   catalogued.

I would add that by keeping the class files in a corresponding folder structure, it is possible to combine complete or partial projects (such as frameworks and/or components) by importing an existing folder structure - without the risk of naming conflicts and/or overwriting existing files.  It also helps finding a particular class when you are working with large code bases.

Comment: I definitely see the logic there in having such conventions, but I'm curious: when the JLS refers to naming conventions, does it imply compiler requirements as well, or does it mean "convention" in the literal sense, i.e., standard practice but not a strict rule?

Comment: I can see how this is misleading, but the quote is taken slightly out of context: The article is a bit longer, and it focuses mainly on how to name your packages (as in "which names should I pick?").  The term "convention" refers to that.  Keeping a consistent file hierarchy is a *requirement*.  Deviations will cause the compilation to fail.